# Django - Filtering query by difference of two DateTimeFields

Tags: python, django

I have a model with two DateTimeFields:

```
starttime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='starttime', blank=False, null=False)
endtime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='endtime', blank=False, null=False)
```

In my view I would like to filter this by the difference between them. For example if the difference between start and end is more than 45 seconds.

I tried this as a guess:

```
        .filter((models.F('endtime') - models.F('starttime')).seconds > 45)\
```

But that didn't work. Is there a way to do this with the Django ORM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the F expression as shown below.

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.utils import timezone


.filter(endtime__gt = models.F('starttime') + timezone.timedelta(0, 45))
```

It will return only the rows which endtime is greater than starttime + 45 seconds.